# How can I use different urls for different store views in magento?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url, mod-rewrite

I have different store views in my magento shop for different languages. I can access them through

```
www.serverdomain.from.my.hoster.tld/langkey/
```

The langkeys are the codes of the different store views and I enabled "add store code to urls".

Now, I want to use my following registered domains without editing index.php

```
www.myshopsite.langkey
```

for example:

```
www.myshopsite.de
www.myshopsite.en
www.myshopsite.com
```

For that I tried to set MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE via htaccess till I realized that they are used to get different stores and not different store views.

Since I configured the base URL for my german store view I can access it via

```
www.myshopsite.de/de/
```

Now I am trying to internally redirect from www.myshopsite.de/ to www.myshopsite.de/de/ to remove the trailing store view code.

Thats my try which ended in a redirect to www.myshopsite.de/en/ and an internal server error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ de/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) de/$1 [L]
```

I am sorry if my fault is obvious.

Comment: After e little deeper test I figured out that my configuration does not work properly. I am grateful for any hint to configure my magento shop (1.7.x) to display the store view depending on the URL without editing index.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this at the bottom of your `.htaccess` file located in your Magento root directory.

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.myshopsite.\.$ MAGE_RUN_CODE=$1
```

The `MAGE_RUN_CODE` variable is for the Magento Store View.  You essentially set it to the store view code set under `System > Manage Stores > Store View`

I've done quite a bit of these configurations so I know that sometimes your server environment setup (apache etc) may differ, and using SetEnvIf in .htaccess may not work.  If that is the case, you may be better off inserting a bit of code into the `index.php` that achieves the results you are looking for.

Yes, it's modifying a core file, however given this scenario is might be more stable to have PHP handle the store variable mapping rather than apache.

Comment: Thank you so much. This variable is the one I was searching for. Meanwhile the customer called and the specs have changed ... :D. We need different stores (not store views) because we have to display different products in the countries. But I will try your hint and be happy to now the new variable :)